# JS fetch against Laravel Api controller does not know user

Tags: laravel

#### Goal:

If a user is currently logged in, the Controller should be recognised. Otherwise he is saved as anonymous. I use Laravel sanctum.

#### Code

**CommentController.php**

```php
if (auth()->user()) {
    $data['user'] => $auth->user()->name;
} else {
   $data['user'] => 'guest';
}

Model::create($data);
```

**config/auth.php**

```php
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],    
    ],
```

**api.php**

`Route::resource('comments', App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::class);`

**blade (javascript fetch part)**

```js
//...
const formData = new FormData(data);
const url = '/api/comments';
let fetchData = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: new Headers({
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value
    })
}

fetch(url, fetchData)...
//...
```

#### Problem

Unfortunately the user is not recognised. `auth()->user()` is always null for api requests. It works via the webRoutes.

Comment: Please can you show how you're setting the `auth` for your api routes.

Comment: @Rwd I did not have an api guard yet. but I have added one (question updated). cleared the cache and tried again. unfortunately the user is not recognised in the controller.

Comment: @Rwd Okay. I forgot to modified the kernel.php with ` \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,`. Now it works! Thank you Rwd

Answer (score 0):

Web and api routes are registered in the [RouteServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php). 
As you can see, web routes have the `web` middleware and api routes have `api` middleware.

`Web` middleware starts session and using cookies to keep your user logged in. 
But `api` middleware does not do this. Usually it requires a token to authorize  the user in every single request.

Laravel has been coming out of the box with [laravel/sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/sanctum) for a while. It has an excellent documentation, and it's easy to use. With this package you can routes that requires authentication.

Alternatives:

- [laravel/passport](https://laravel.com/docs/passport) (oAuth 2 server)